# Read XML in UTF-8 VB6

Tags: xml, utf-8, vb6, xmldom

I have this XML with ▲ character in UTF-8.

However, when I read this XML, this character is displayed as "?"
I have no idea how to change it, any help would be appreciated.

Here is so far what I did:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <rss version="2.0">
        <reg>
           <myitem>  ▲ |  ▼</myitem>
        </reg>
   </rss>
```

Reading this XML:

```
Set oXml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
oXml.async = False
oXml.Load http://localhost:8080/project/myxml.jsp
Set myTag = oXml.getElementsByTagName("reg")
```

then retrieving a this tag:

```
myTag.item(1).getElementsByTagName("myitem").item(0).Text
```

and my result is `? | ?`

any idea how to get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldeclaration.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: @JimGarrison it did not work, cannot recognize most of object type (XmlDocument, XmlDeclaration ,XmlElement )

Comment: It is probably working just fine, you are probably trying to display the text using an ANSI control, `Debug.Print`, etc. when you need a Unicode-aware display medium.  Windows Vista and later include an InkEdit control for VB6 programs which can be a handy Unicode TextBox/RichTextBox for many purposes.

Comment: I'm trying to display the text inside my label, and i'm also using windows xp for this (got this project this way, and cannot change OS)

Answer (score 0):

The header might say UTF-8 but the actual file must be UTF-16. Easiest way to confirm: open the XML file in Windows Notepad and choose "File->Save As". A small dropdown box near the "Save" button will show "Unicode" or "Ascii"